# Symfony2 - Persist entity without persisting its association

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

Im having big troubles with this issue since a month already.

Database :

--Tables :

1- "Profession" : Pre-filled

2- "User"

In my entity "User" I have :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="M\CoreBundle\Entity\Profession", cascade={"persist"} )
*/
protected $profession;
```

I do create a FormType, where I fetch all the professions that will be displayed in a dropdown list.

```
...
->add('profession', 'entity', array(
'label'  => 'Profession',
'empty_value' => 'Sélectionnez',
'class' => 'MCoreBundle:Profession',
'query_builder' => function($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.nom, p.id', 'ASC'); },
'property' => 'nom',
'required'  => true
))
...
```

When im about to flush my "User" entity :

```
$oEm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$oUser->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));
$oImages->setUser($oUser);

// On le persiste
$oEm->persist($oUser);
$oEm->persist($oImages);

// On déclenche l'enregistrement
$oEm->flush();
```

**Problem** : 
My data are saved very well, BUT it records me a new line on the "Profession" table.

**Question** : 
How can I do so that Symfony saves the User without saving its association which is "Profession" ?

Thanks for help

PS : Im on **Symfony 2.2.8**

Comment: Shall one `User` be able to have multiple `Profession`s in your application? Do i understand it correctly that you want to persist a new `User` linked to **one** pre-existing `Profession` ... but the application creates a new profession in the table upon persisting instead of linking the pre-existing one you choose in the entity-field?

Comment: Thanks for answering,
Yes, a User shall have ONE profession, and instead of linking the user with the existing profession, it adds a new line on the Profession table, that kills me !

Comment: I think you need to remove the cascade option from the mapping. Why did you addid specifically? Can you check what is the content of the profession before persist also?

Comment: When I do that I get : 
    A new entity was found through the relationship 'M\CoreBundle\Entity\User#profession' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: M\CoreBundle\Entity\Profession@00000000018bd03c000000006b4f0a4b. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'M\CoreBundle\Entity\Profession#__toString()' to get a clue.

Comment: **Important** : If it can help you, before I persist when I make :
 
    $oUser->setProfession($oEm->getRepository('MCoreBundle:Profession')->find($oUser->getProfession()->getId()));

It works, and it doesnt add a new line on the Profession table.
I do check the content of the attrib Profession on the $oUser object, and its **THE SAME** before and after the operation above.

And I have 5 other associated entitys with the same problem, the solution that I just gave wont be optimized (lot of contacts with DB for nothing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution (Halleluja) !

Actually I was transfering the object $oUser trough different pages and when I flush it, I do that for the foreign tables that were previously loaded, thats why the EntityManager doesnt recognize them and make a new lines on the table.

Thank you.